# update function of Component not called anymore

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

The update function of Component is not called anymore in Cocos2dx v3 while it was called fine in v2.x

I noticed the CCScheduler is completely different in both versions and that Node::update in v2 is called from CCScheduler::update function but in v3 it is called from Scene::update - which is never called.

Anybody have an idea what is the best way to migrate this from v2 to v3.

My code is as follows

In game scene

```
layerMoveLeft = ParallaxNode::create();
layerMoveLeft->addComponent(new MoveLeft() );
this->addChild(layerMoveLeft);
```

In MoveLeft class -

```
class MoveLeft : public Component
...

void MoveLeft::onEnter()
{
     log("- MoveLeft::onEnter");
}

void MoveLeft::update(float delta) {
    log("- MoveLeft::update"); 
}
```

The update function in v3 is never called

Answer (score 0):

in V 3+ you can call update method on Node class using `ScheduleUpdate()` function call.

```
 virtual void update(float dt);
```

I don't know why you want Component class in V 3.0

Comment: I am actually migrating my V 2 project to V 3+.. If you can tell me what is the alternative to Component mechanism it would be great

Comment: Do I call ScheduleUpdate on the 'onEnter' function of the Component?

Comment: Component Class is sub Class of Ref Class.  i think you can use scheduleUpdate() . Just give it a try.

Comment: this could be helpful to you : http://www.redtgames.com/blog/cocos2d-x-v2-to-v3-mapping-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes and i hope that it will work.

**MoveLeft.h**

```
void update(float delta);
```

**MoveLeft.cpp**

```
this->scheduleUpdate();
```

You can add the above code anywhere you want in the class (preferably in the init() method)
Now create the function as you did before:

```
void MoveLeft::update(float delta) {
    log("- MoveLeft::update"); 
}
```

**P.S**: I haven't used it with Component, i have used it with Layer.

```
class Quizzes: public cocos2d::Layer{
 public:
      virtual bool init();
}
```

Comment: thanks will give it a try. am using it with Component and adding that to a   ParrallaxNode

Answer (score 0):

in V 3+, you can add code above to class parent of component.

```
this->scheduleUpdate();
```